# How to cut a hole through kitchen ceramic floor tile to install pop-up electrical box?

Tags: receptacle, ceramic-tile, kitchen-island

I'd like to install [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07RJYY8C7) ([Manufc. Page](https://www.leviton.com/en/products/pfgf2-bn)) 20A GFCI pop-up electrical box in the kitchen floor to allow cookware (microwave, blender, air fryer) to be plugged in. I will build a kitchen island cart to house the microwave and store the other cookware.

I need to make a plunge cut for a hole through a 12"x12" 5/16"-thick ceramic tile and through the subfloor underneath to house the outlet and run a 20A line to the breaker box.

I have a wired Fein Multimaster oscillating tool but there isn't any literature on what blade to use to cut ceramic tile. I have an angle grinder, which I know could do the job, but the circular blade means I can't make a complete cut at a corner.

Comment: Kitchen floors often get wet. Wet electrical outlets can be hazardous. A pendant cord hanging from the ceiling might be a better way to have an outlet available at your cart location.

Comment: There should be no plugs in kitchen floor. What if someone mops the floor ?

Comment: As for cutting, use diamond blade on slow speed with lots of water. The more cutting teeth on the blade the better.

Comment: A carbide blade _might_ cut through the tile, depending on the hardness.  A diamond blade will certainly work.  A [segment blade](https://fein.com/en_us/accessories/segment-blade-63903196013/) gives you a fair bit of cutting length, but still allows you to work into corners.

Comment: @Ruskes your concerns are valid. For these reasons, I opted for a box design where the plug interface is raised above ground, tilted upwards at an angle and not recessed into the floor. It is GFCI protected and there is a gasket where the outlet shuts (the outlet itself is IP44 rated).

Comment: Unless code forbids putting a pop-up outlet on a kitchen floor, I will regard this as doable (because the risk of water ingress from mopping/splashing can happen *anywhere* e.g., a person spilling water onto a floor outlet in the living room). In addition, these are marketed as installable on countertops, where there is *surely* a higher risk of spills.

Comment: Google “tile blade for fein”. If you’ve got porcelain tiles, buy a spare blade.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Drill the corners, Score & Break the sides

With a handheld "tile scoring tool" you can also score a rectangle after drilling the corners, and tap with a hammer to break up the tile within the rectangle.

Select a bit that is small enough so that the face plate covers the curve. Carefully tap away anything that remains, using a hammer and a mason chisel or maybe an old wood chisel.

### Angle Grinder, Drill the corners

Or you can use the **angle grinder** for round or rectangular holes, as you stated. Since you don't have access to both faces of the tile, you will have over/under cut. As with the score & tap approach, the trick is to drill the corners.

### Hole Saw for wire only

For a round hole you can use a "Tile Hole Saw" for this:

[image]

This would allow passage of the wire. The outlet could then be on a raised box, with a cover or faced sideways, to prevent liquids from flowing in. This is especially important if it is located in the "wet area" of the kitchen: near sinks, stove, and dishwasher, within reasonable flooding area. If it is not in a tripping area you could raise it even just by 0.5 inch.

Comment: I _love_ my oscillating saw, but it is _not_ the right tool for every job.